# Music software that would allow me to edit tracks

Tags: windows, music

I am looking for a program that would allow me to edit tracks. What I want to do is:

- Cut tracks. (like remove the last 2 minutes of a song etc)
- Increase/Decrease the pitch

I am using Windows and I would prefer a free software

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is the software, you are looking for. It's free, open source, cross-platform audio editor.
What I like is that it supports many audio formats. You require [LAME encoder library](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) to export MP3 files. 
Some notable features are

- **Easy editing with Cut, Copy, Paste and Delete.**
- Unlimited sequential Undo (and Redo) to go back any number of steps.
- Edit and mix large numbers of tracks.
- **Change the pitch without altering the tempo (or vice-versa).**
- Remove static, hiss, hum or other constant background noises.
- Alter frequencies with Equalization, Bass and Treble, High/Low Pass and Notch Filter effects.
- Adjust volume with Compressor, Amplify, Normalize, Fade In/Fade Out and Adjustable Fade effects.
- Remove Vocals from suitable stereo tracks.

It has also a nice, user-friendly interface.
I am not using Audacity currently. I used this around 2 years ago. I am not that hardcore music editor. My work doesn't require anything other than 'Cut, Copy, Paste and Delete' feature. So in this 2 years many new things have been added to the software and things like stability, reliability must have improved. At least we can hope this from a open source software like Audacity.